# How to configure linux guest that will have dynamic space , did set 25.00 GB virtual size but it keep running out of space

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Virtual box Version 7.0.8 r156879 (Qt5.15.2) on windows ,
i configured ubuntu as guest OS on windows VB , all working good , i was thinking that if i set
virtual size to 25g it will be enough .
But it keeps running out of space i don't understand why .
for example when i do :

```
tmux
couldn't create directory /tmp/tmux-1000 (No space left on device)

This is what i see from my guest linux machine
 df -H
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              411M  1.3M  410M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   13G   12G     0 100% /
tmpfs                              2.1G     0  2.1G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                          2.1G  154M  1.8G   8% /boot
tmpfs                              411M  4.1k  411M   1% /run/user/1000
```

it is not 25g , also what is this /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv

This is my config of vb:
[image]

Comment: We have no way at all of knowing what is taking up the space. That is something you will have to investigate for yourself, perhaps using `du`